# Remove reversed tuples with same third-tier column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, hql

How can I remove reversed (m,n) <-> (n,m) with the same Letter ?

```
Table
id1;id2;Letter
1;2;"A"
3;4;"B"
4;3;"B" ->  row to be deleted or the one above(3;4;"B"), no matter which one
5;6;"C"
6;5;"C" ->  row to be deleted or the one above(5;6;"C"), no matter which one
1;2;"B"
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: What if `id1` = `id2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach to do this delete is:

```
delete 
  from table t
      USING table t2
 where t.id1 > t.id2
   and t.id1 = t2.id2 
   and t.id2 = t2.id1
   and t.Letter = t2.Letter;
```

You also should consider to add two validations a constraint and an index to prevent such scenario to happen again:

```
alter table table add constraint chk_diff_ids CHECK (id1 != id2);
```

This `CHECK CONSTRAINT` will avoid id1 beeing insert equals to id2 something like `1;1;'A'`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_reverse_value
    ON table ( Letter, LEAST(id1,id2), GREATEST(id1,id2) );
```

This index will prevent a creation of an inverted values as you want to delete then, so if you have `1,2,'B'` it will prevent will to insert `2,1,'B'`

Note: `table` is a reserved word you shouldn't use it as a table name :)

See it working here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17f00/2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this syntax works for PostgreSQL (I haven't worked with it in a few years)

```
DELETE MT
FROM
    My_Table MT
WHERE
    MT.id1 > MT.id2 AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            My_Table MT2
        WHERE
            MT2.id1 = MT.id2 AND
            MT2.id2 = MT.id1 AND
            MT2.letter = MT.letter  -- If this is also part of the requirement, otherwise you need logic on which row to keep
    )
```

Comment: Yeah it works, I just have to use "!=" instead of "=" inside the second where to get the rows without the bad lines. Thank you for your replying so quickly